# St_area and St_length on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to plot a bunch of areas on a Google map. The locational elements of the data seem to be in St_area and St_length fields. I can't find much about this format. Is anyone familiar with how I can convert this to a set of coordinates that I can then put on a Google map?

Data here:

https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/da831f80764346889837c72508f046fa_3

[image]

Comment: The download button allows you to download as shapefile or KML (you can overlay KML on google maps) > https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml

Comment: Yes but unfortunately the locational elements i.e. st_area and st_length are not recognised by google even if I upload in KML so it doesn't work. I suspect I need to convert them to something else.

Comment: st_length and st_area aren't locational elements but attributes of the features. There should be shape or feature coordinates--map those instead.

Comment: Apologies, I have added what the data looks like in the OP. st_areashape and st_lengthshape must be the locational elements are there isnt any other data there!

Comment: Can you please elucidate what do you mean by `"a set of coordinates"`? And as was already mentioned before, it is possible to download as KML which can be displayed in Google Maps API, check documentation [Displaying KML](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml). I hope you meant Google Maps API, did not you? Or you are talking about simple Google Maps? In that case, I will suggest using Google Earth where you can easily "drag&drop" your data in various formats in terms you just want to preview the data set.

Comment: What I am trying to do is make a bespoke google map ("my maps" not an API) where I overay a bunch of pins/areas I am interested in on a map. Google needs to know where to draw those areas of interest hence my reference to location coordinates. I was under the impression that the st_areashape and st_lenthshape in the data above were coordinates that google could plot.  I get that I can download a KML, but when I upload that to google maps My Maps feature the pins don't plot. I guess it doesn't understand the format or something. Other pins work fine.